# Dynamically update treemap elements with D3.js

Tags: d3.js, treemap

I'm experimenting with implementing a treemap using D3.js and the following example:
http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/treemap.html

So far it works pretty good.

My problem is if I would like to refresh the treemap items using transition for a completely new set of data, I cannot do it. I can only do this if I reinitialize the treemap object.

Let's take a simple example:

DATASET1: PROD1, PROD2, PROD3...
DATASET2: LOC1, LOC2, LOC3, LOC4...

I would like to have a transition animation when switching between the two datasets, which have different number of elements and different sizes (values). Again, I could only do it by basically removing the elements of the parent DIV id ($("#treemap_1").empty();) and then recreate the whole treemap with the new dataset.

Sorry, I'm very new to D3.js, so maybe it's something obvious. :)

Thanks & best regards,
Bence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the same as [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10520280/111884).

[The problem is with the treemap being `sticky`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520641/111884).

Comment: Agreed—it's likely either the sticky flag or the data join. See my answer on the other question.