# D3.js update Treemap dynamically

Tags: d3.js, treemap

i want to update a Treemap dynamicly with new Data. I have read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530789/dynamically-update-treemap-elements-with-d3-js?lq=1) but i do not bring it up and running. So this is my code:

```
function buildTreemap(jVals){
    //$("#treemap").empty();

    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(jVals);

    var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
        width = 760 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .size([width, height])
        .sticky(true)
        .sort(function(a,b) { return a.anzahl - b.anzahl; })
        .round(true)
        .value(function(d) { return Math.log(d.anzahl); });

    var div = d3.select("#treemap").append("div")
        .style("position", "relative")
        .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
        .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px")
        .style("left", margin.left + "px")
        .style("top", margin.top + "px")
        .attr("id", "first");

    var node = div.datum(data).selectAll(".node")
        .data(treemap.nodes)
        .enter().append("div")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .style("left", function(d) { return d.x + "px"; })
        .style("top", function(d) { return d.y + "px"; })
        .style("width", function(d) {  return Math.max(0, d.dx - 1) + "px"; })
        .style("height", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dy - 1) + "px"; })
        .style("background", function(d) { return d.color ? d.color : "#ffffff";})
        .text(function(d) { return d.children ? "blue" : d.keytable + "(" + d.anzahl + "-" + Math.max(0, d.dx) + "-" + Math.max(0, d.dy) + ")"; })
        ;

};
```

From another Js-Function i call buildTreemap() with new data. Now i want the treemap to redraw with Transition/Duration.

Could anybody help me please. 
Thanks a lot...

**Update:**
I have added this:

```
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
        var value = this.value === "count"
            ? function() { return 1; }
            : function(d) { return Math.log(d.anzahl); };

        node
            .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .call(position);
    });
```

and with this code the treemap rebuilds if i click "change"-Input. But if i take this code:

```
d3.selectAll("#search").on("keyup", function change() {
        var value = function(d) { return Math.log(d.anzahl); };

        node
            .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .call(position);
    });
```

the treemap stays and another treemap with the new data-values opens below my first. On keyup another js-function is fired and send new data to buildTreemap().

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582)?

Comment: Yes but this only rescale the size of the divs with the same data. I need a rescaling with new data.

Comment: The principle is the same. It's still passing new data to the treemap layout on change.

Comment: Hm, please have a look at my update.

Comment: Can you post your complete code somewhere, preferably on jsfiddle? It's hard to see what's going on without the complete picture.

Comment: Ok now...have a look at this fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/maker23/WB5jh/1/

There are two data-objects. the first i want to load at first an the second i want to load if i click the button.

Answer (score 3):

I've simplified and modified your jsfiddle slightly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WB5jh/3/) to show the second set of data when you click the button. The key is that inside the function you call when the button is clicked, you pass in the new data like you did when you initialised the treemap and then handle enter and update selections accordingly, like so:

```
var node = div.datum(data2).selectAll(".node")
          .data(treemap.nodes);
node.enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", "node");

node.transition().duration(1500).call(position)
    .style("background", function(d) { return d.color ? d.color : "#ffffff"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.children ? "blue" : d.keytable + "(" + d.anzahl + "-" + Math.max(0, d.dx) + "-" + Math.max(0, d.dy) + ")"; });
```

Note that the enter selection merges into the update selection, so it is sufficient to just append the nodes and set the attributes on the update selection.

Comment: Ok very nice! But if i take more complex data the behavior is very strange. Look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/maker23/WB5jh/4/

Comment: I think the old nodes are left in the treemap and the new ones are pushed...somethink like this?!!?!

Comment: Just add `node.exit().remove()` at the end of the change function.

Comment: In response to your other problem, it looks like you're passing in malformed data.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see any wrong formatting.

My first data is:

```
{
    "name": "items",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "33447",
            "anzahl": "13",
            "color": "#ff8080",
            "keytable": "CCR",
            "bordercolor": "#B25959"
        },
        {
            "id": "33455",
            "anzahl": "4",
            "color": "#80ff80",
            "keytable": "COMMODITY",
            "bordercolor": "#59B259"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "anzahl": "37",
            "color": "#80ffff",
            "keytable": "COUNTRY",
            "bordercolor": "#59B2B2"
        },
        {
            "id": "33465",
            "anzahl": "3",
            "color": "#ff0000",
            "keytable": "FUNDS",
            "bordercolor": "#B20000"
        },
        {
            "id": "67400",
            "anzahl": "22",
            "color": "#ffff00",
            "keytable": "GOVERNMENT",
            "bordercolor": "#B2B200"
        },
        {
            "id": "29",
            "anzahl": "183",
            "color": "#008080",
            "keytable": "INDEX",
            "bordercolor": "#005959"
        },
        {
            "id": "33449",
            "anzahl": "1",
            "color": "#8080ff",
            "keytable": "INTER",
            "bordercolor": "#5959B2"
        },
        {
            "id": "67422",
            "anzahl": "8",
            "color": "#800000",
            "keytable": "PARTY",
            "bordercolor": "#590000"
        },
        {
            "id": "33358",
            "anzahl": "4",
            "color": "#8000ff",
            "keytable": "PM",
            "bordercolor": "#5900B2"
        },
        {
            "id": "30",
            "anzahl": "1920",
            "color": "#f90631",
            "keytable": "SHARE",
            "bordercolor": "#AE0422"
        },
        {
            "id": "81",
            "anzahl": "70960",
            "color": "#11b1ee",
            "keytable": "WARRANT",
            "bordercolor": "#0B7BA6"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "anzahl": "1",
            "color": "#004000",
            "keytable": "WORLD",
            "bordercolor": "#002C00"
        }
    ]
}
```

and the second data is:

```
{
    "name": "items",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "29",
            "anzahl": "12",
            "color": "#008080",
            "keytable": "INDEX",
            "bordercolor": "#005959"
        },
        {
            "id": "55645",
            "anzahl": "165",
            "color": "#11b1ee",
            "keytable": "WARRANT",
            "bordercolor": "#0B7BA6"
        }
    ]
}
```

Ok in the console it looks different...but why:

data1:

```
Object {name: "items", children: Array[12]}
area: 333000
children: Array[12]
depth: 0
dx: 740
dy: 450
name: "items"
value: 39.15699051089851
x: 0
y: 0
__proto__: Object
```

data2:

```
Object {name: "items", children: Array[2]}
children: Array[2]
name: "items"
__proto__: Object
```

But the children are also in there...

**UPDATE:**

I think on data2 the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined" means that one of the datasets is missing.

In the fiddle both datasets where definded within the function. But in my live-example the datasets where passed to the function. Likie this:

```
function buildTreemap(jVals_all, jVals_filtered, doRebuild){

if(doRebuild === false){
    var data1 = jQuery.parseJSON(jVals_all);
}
if(doRebuild === true){
    var data2 = jQuery.parseJSON(jVals_filtered);
}
....
}
```

So is it possible that if i send data2 the function is missing the children of data1 because data1 is empty??

At the end i want to pass only one object to the function...

```
function buildTreemap(data){}
```

If this is easier to solve, then i will prefer this way.